# Can a checked exception & unchecked exception have a common parent exception?

Tags: java, exception

So, these are my use-cases

1. Use-case where it's not useful to catch the exception and it needs to be thrown all the way out - Unchecked exception
2. Use-case where a certain exception needs to be handled most often than not - Checked exception
3. To have a common parent for the above exceptions(doesn't matter the type) since they're both related and so I can catch and record metrics easily

Is there any way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: There is only one parent and it is `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: @tsolakp And [`java.lang.Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), the parent of [`java.lang.Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

Comment: @tsolakp - nope, it's `Throwable`, since `Error` is also unchecked.

Comment: @Andreas. The comment was in the context of question. Usually it is bad practice to catch `java.lang.Throwable`. "The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch."